# shell is not substituting the variable values

Tags: bash, shell

Whats wrong with my script ?

```
echo "Environment validation started"
ID=`getValueFromFile "ID"`
echo $ID
FAILLOG=$HOME/$ID/logs/1.log
echo $FAILLOG
echo $HOME/$ID/logs/1.log
>$FAILLOG
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Environment validation started
JASONID
/logs/1.log
/logs/1.log
/logs/1.log: No such file or directory/home/gol/JASONID
```

ideally echo should give something like this right?

```
/home/gol/JASONID/logs/1.log
```

adding bash -vx output

```
+ echo $'JASONID\r'
JASONID
FAILLOG=$HOME/$ID/logs/1.log
+ FAILLOG=$'/home/gol/JASONID\r/logs/1.log'
echo $FAILLOG
+ echo $'/home/gol/JASONID\r/logs/1.log'
/logs/1.log
echo $HOME/$ID/logs/1.log
+ echo $'/home/gol/JASONID\r/logs/1.log'
/logs/1.log
```

Comment: Do you have carriage returns in the file you're getting `ID` from?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes this is sample content ID=JASONID
SOL_SELECTED=1
DIRECTORY=YES,after every word i have carriage return

Comment: Add the output of `bash -vx your_script.sh` to your question.

Comment: The `\r` is the problem them, it's part of the value of `ID` and so your susbstituted string is something like `/home/gol/JSONID\r/logs/1.log` which causes the `/logs/1.log` to appear over the start of the string

Comment: @EricRenouf you are right updating the question with bash -vx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@EricRenouf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109842/eric-renouf) commented, if whatever goes to `ID` has a carriage return (`\r`) in the end, it will mangle the output by moving the cursor to the start of the string, after which the rest will overwrite the leading parts.

Using `printf %q` to see the special characters:

```
ID=$'abcdef\r'
echo "$ID/123"
printf "%q\n" "$ID/123"
```

we get:

```
/123ef
$'abcdef\r/123'
```

You can use parameter expansions to remove the final CR:

```
ID=${ID%$'\r'}
echo "$ID/123"
printf "%q\n" "$ID/123"
```

(`$'..'` is nonstandard IIRC, but it works in Bash and others.)

Comment: but can i omit the "carriage return /r" while reading ? or from delete from file itself ?

Comment: @Jason, oh, sure, of course you can also edit the input file with something like `dos2unix`, or `sed -i -e $'s/\r//' file`